# How do I open a text file that's in my app's package?

Tags: android, eclipse, file-io, java-io

Using Eclipse, Android SDK.

I have a text file full of data that I need pulled in. (For now, it's the easier the way, eventually I'm going to need to scrape dynamic data from a URL, but for now I have the test data I need in this text file).

I've created a class to open this file, but no matter how I try to open it I keep geeting "file not found" exceptions.

I've tried putting my "data.txt" file in various relative paths (within my App):
 - "/AppName/"
 - "/AppName/src/com/example/appname/data.txt"

I've tried passing different relative paths. I've tried putting the text file in the same path of the .java class file that's trying to open it, and it still can't find it! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to read about Assets and /res/raw. You should not put the text file into your source directories.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

You have two main options of where to store this file within your project directory: `assets/` and `res/raw/`.

If you use `assets/`, you can call `getAssets()` on your `Activity` (or other `Context`), and on there call `open()` with the relative path within `assets/` to get an `InputStream` on this file (e.g., `assets/data.txt` would be accessed via `getAssets().open("data.txt")`).

If you use `res/raw/`, you can call `getResources()` on your `Activity` (or other `Context`), and on there call `openRawResource()`, passing in the `R.raw` value based upon your filename (e.g., `res/raw/data.txt` would be accessed via `getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data)`).

Comment: Thanks! I can now open the file at least, I've confirmed it through watching the debug trace. Now I can't get my InputStreamReader to get anything, haha! Oy....

Answer (score 0):

Use /res/raw directory. I read sound files from raw:

```
InputStream soundFile1 = context.getResources().openRawResource(soundOneId);
```

Where context is a base context of activity passed to the class.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html